# Is there any way to restrict a generic type to one of several types?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a generic struct which uses an "integer type" for references into an array. For performance reasons I'd like to be able to specify easily whether to use `u16`, `u32` or `u64`. Something like this (which obviously isn't valid Rust code):

```
struct Foo<T: u16 or u32 or u64> { ... }
```

Is there any way to express this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sometimes you may want to use an `enum` rather than a generic type with a trait bound. For example:

```
enum Unsigned {
    U16(u16),
    U32(u32),
    U64(u64),
}

struct Foo { x: Unsigned, ... };
```

One advantage of making a new type over implementing a new trait for existing types is that you can add foreign traits and inherent behavior to the new type. You can implement any traits you like for `Unsigned`, like `Add`, `Mul`, etc. When `Foo` contains an `Unsigned`, implementing traits  on `Unsigned` doesn't affect the signature of `Foo` like it would to add them as bounds on `Foo`'s parameter (e.g. `Foo<T: Add<Output=Self> + PartialCmp + ...>`). On the other hand, you do still have to implement each trait.

Another thing to note: while you can generally always make a new type and implement a trait for it, an enum is "closed": you can't add new types to `Unsigned` without touching the rest of its implementation, like you could if you used a trait. This may be a good thing or a bad thing depending on what your design calls for.

---

"Performance reasons" is a bit ambiguous, but if you're thinking of storing a lot of `Unsigned`s that will all be the same internal type, and this:

```
struct Foo([Unsigned; 1_000_000]);
```

would waste a ton of space over storing a million `u16`s, you can still make `Foo` generic! Just implement `From<u16>`, `From<u32>`, and `From<u64>` for `Unsigned` and write this instead:

```
struct Foo<T: Into<Unsigned>>([T; 1_000_000]);
```

Now you only have one simple trait bound on `T`, you're not wasting space for tags and padding, and functions that deal with `T` can always convert it to `Unsigned` to do calculations with. The cost of the conversion may even be optimized away entirely.

#### See Also

- [Should I use enum to emulate the polymorphism or use trait with Box<trait> instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240099/should-i-use-enum-to-emulate-the-polymorphism-or-use-trait-with-boxtrait-inste)

Comment: omg. Exactly what I was looking for lol. I didn't realize that I could use tuple structs inside enums that way, but now that I think about it it really makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Just to add that the `num` crate already did the job for you: https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/traits/trait.Unsigned.html

Answer (score 41):

For references into an array usually you'd just use a `usize` rather than different integer types.

However, to do what you are after you can create a new trait, implement that trait for `u16`, `u32` and `u64` and then restrict T to your new trait.

```
pub trait MyNewTrait {}

impl MyNewTrait for u16 {}
impl MyNewTrait for u32 {}
impl MyNewTrait for u64 {}

struct Foo<T: MyNewTrait> { ... }
```

You may then also add methods onto `MyNewTrait` and the `impl`s to encapsulate the logic specific to `u16`, `u32` and `u64`.

Comment: Yes, but that does not allow me to do everything I could do with an u16, u32 or u64 - e.g. I could not use a value to retrieve an element of an array, compare two values, etc.

Comment: @HenningKoehler: You can, you just have to declare it at trait level. That is `pub trait MyNewTrait: Add<Output = Self> + Mul<Output = Self> + ... {}`

Comment: I suppose, but that also becomes tedious pretty quickly.. and for referencing into a vector I'd need a conversion into usize, which doesn't seem very safe for arbitrary types that can be added, multiplied etc...

Comment: @HenningKoehler You could add another trait restriction on your struct or trait for `Into<usize>`. Either `T: MyNewTrait + Into<usize>` or `trait MyNewTrait : Into<usize>`